# How do I export reports from Reporting Services 2005 to Excel without the references to other cells?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export, reportingservices-2005

I am using `Reporting services 2005`, and am exporting the reports into `Excel`.  Everything is fine except for cells that have been referenced to.  An example is this:

*textbox1* has the value 10
*textbox2* has the value 20
the formula in *textbox3* is

```
=ReportItems!textbox1.value + ReportItems!textbox2.value
```

*textbox3* would have the correct result 30 on the reporting services display.

but when i export the report to excel, the value where textbox should be is the reference to the location of *textbox1* and *textbox2* in the excel sheet instead of the value.

how can i export the value and not the references to the other two cells?

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a textbox.value in a formula that adds two [numbers] together you need to change the datatype:

textbox1.value **=10**
textbox2.value **=20**
textbox3.value **=CInt(ReportItems!textbox1.value) + CInt(ReportItems!textbox2.value)**

When you export this report into Excel you will have each value (10|20) and the sum of the two - without the reference to the cells they occupy.

I hope this helps.